# how to load pretty printer for qt with lldb

Tags: c++, qt, gdb, clion, lldb

according to [Clion official manual](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/qt-tutorial.html#debug-renderers), it's possible to have a readable qt type in debugger, but it's not working.

I followed the manual, downloaded [lldb_formatters](https://github.com/KDE/kdevelop/tree/master/plugins/lldb/formatters) and added to .lldbinit under project source like [this](https://github.com/ivany4/lldb-qt#installation).

```
//${project_source}/.lldbinit
 command script import ~/lldb_formatters/all.py
```

qstring and qvector turn invalid after the script is imported

I wonder if there're steps I missed

Comment: Use the `type {summary/synthetic} info VarName` command, where `VarName` is a variable that has one of the types this file should format.  That will tell you if the formatter is being correctly registered for that type.  You can use `v --raw VarName` to make sure the values are available (sometimes values aren't initialized, etc).  If the formatter is recognized & the underlying value seems okay, then it might be the formatter's code is incorrect.

Comment: You can edit the lldb_formatters.py file, adding the line: `breakpoint()` at the beginning of the formatter function for the type that wasn't working.  Then when you run `v VarName`, you'll stop in the Python debugger, and can step through the formatter code to see what the problem is.  These formatters often depend on implementation details of a given type, so it's possible that the layout has changed but the formatters haven't kept up to date, or something  like that.

Answer (score 2):

For Qt5 check [lldb-qt-formatters](https://github.com/pavolmarkovic-serato/lldb-qt-formatters)

For Qt6 check [qt6-renderer plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/19882-qt6-renderer)

Neither is perfect but at least something.

Comment: I've tried this plugin, it's amazing!